# Static IP address changed to another static IP address. What needs to be changed?

Tags: 10.04, server, configuration

My static IP was on Verizon's network, who are subletting their Fios lines to Frontier. Now I am given a new static IP from Frontier's data network. May I have a ballpark list of configurations to change to the new IP? It is like me to miss one thing and cause a problem. I have a LAMP with proftpd & ssh tunneling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checklist:

- Firewall: if you've put a firewall rule in which denies all traffic which where not designated for your IP, you need to change that.
- Interfaces file: Change the static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces`. This file is re-read when the network connection is set up again.
- ProFTPd: the address on which ProFTPd is listening on
- Apache: the address on which Apache is listening on. Also check your virtual host settings like `<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4>` and `NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4`.
- MySQL: check the address it's listening on. Usually, this is set to listen on all addresses.
- DNS: all records which point to your IP.
- To make sure you did not forget anything, search all files on your server for the old IP address using:

  ```
  sudo grep -HrnF '1.2.3.4' /
  ```

  This command shows every occurence of the IP address `1.2.3.4` as `filename:line: line with 1.2.3.4`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I ran the grep command but ran into this:
`sudo@server:~$ sudo grep -HrnF '1.2.3.4' /

grep: /usr/share/doc/bash/completion-contrib: No such file or directory

grep: /usr/share/doc/libsane/supported.html: No such file or directory

grep: /usr/share/man/man5/modprobe.d.5: No such file or directory

grep: warning: /usr/bin/X11: recursive directory loop

grep: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-28-server/source: No such file or directory`

And the process did not return me to command prompt. Is it safe to assume that my files were searched through?

Comment: @aesthetic priest: When the process has completed, the program will return to shell. If you want to quit the search, press Ctrl + C. Note that this script searches for a literal occurence of `1.2.3.4`. Other forms like `1. 23.234.  5`, `1.2.3.0/24` or `array(1,2,3,4)` are not included. Use it as a tool to find references you've forgotten about.

Comment: Maybe we should add `I` and `--devices=skip` to the grep command otherwise it will hang (don't know the exact reason, but it seems read somewhere in /proc). Next, redirect output to a file `> oldips.txt`, otherwise output may be lost (e.g. if it finds an old mailbox file with lots of old IP addresses).

Comment: It's probably a better idea not to start searching in `/`, but look in `/usr /etc /home /srv /var /boot /opt` (and any additional custom dirs such as `/media /mnt /www /your-own-dir`). Descending in `/proc /sys /dev` is not sensible indeed.