# Searching for file contents on whole disk

Tags: disk, search, grep

I am trying to [find my old IP address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418873/where-does-apticron-get-the-ip-adresses-from) in config files in order to replace it by my new IP address. I [found one answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/35319/242307) that proposes the command

```
sudo grep -HrnF '1.2.3.4' /
```

to find those IP addresses.

However, using this command directly, grep seems to hang. Before it hangs, it outputs some warnings that it cannot access some files inside /proc. Therefore I changed the command to

```
sudo grep -HrnFI --devices=skip '1.2.3.4' / > oldips.txt
```

But this time it wrote a 29 GB text file until I pressed Ctrl+C. After that I excluded the /proc directory like this:

```
 sudo grep -HrnFI --devices=skip --exclude-dir=/proc '1.2.3.4' / > oldips.txt
```

Is this a good way to find an IP address (or text in general) on the whole disk? If not, how would I need to change the command?

Comment: I suspect if you want to grep through your entire file system, it just _will_ take ages. Perhaps limit it to a few directories that are more likely to contain the IP address. e.g. try `/etc` first (instead of `/`).

Comment: Well, if it does something, I can see CPU time being consumed (I'm checking with `top`) by grep, which I think it didn't using the first command, but it does using the last command.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand that comment. Are you saying that grep is doing something because it's using CPU? If so, yes, that's true, but it's going to take ages because it's reading through your entire file system. Instead, try something like `sudo grep -HrnFI --devices=skip '1.2.3.4' /etc > oldips.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likeliest problem is that it will be attempting to enter all the strange files in `/sys` and `/proc` and `/dev` (the first command at least, but `/sys` will still be an issue). Some of those will be long link chains all of which must be followed and none of which are actually of interest to you.

A much cleaner approach would be to use `find` and its exec option. Something like:

```
sudo find / -type f -exec grep -Flm 1 '1.2.3.4' {} +
```

The above command will find all regular files in `/` and run `grep` on them.

- The `-l` means "print the matching file name", which is easier than printing the line and will probably increase your speed as well. Once you have the matching files, you can `grep` them at your leisure.
- The `-m 1` means "stop at the first match", this way large files will not need to be processed all the way through to the end if a match has been found.
- The `+` at the end means that find will try and combine this into as few commands as possible (another reason why `-l` is needed, otherwise you won't know where the file came from). This is documented in `man find`:

  ```
     -exec command ;
            Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
            arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
            an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}'
            is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
            it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
            where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both  of  these
            constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to
            protect them from expansion by the shell.  See the EXAMPLES sec‐
            tion for examples of the use of the -exec option.  The specified
            command is run once for each matched file.  The command is  exe‐
            cuted  in  the starting directory.   There are unavoidable secu‐
            rity problems surrounding use of the -exec  action;  you  should
            use the -execdir option instead.

     -exec command {} +
            This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
            the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
            each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invoca‐
            tions of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
            matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
            that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of  `{}'
            is  allowed  within the command.  The command is executed in the
            starting directory.
  ```

Before running that however, I would recommend you simply run this:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -exec grep -F '1.2.3.4' {} \;
```

The chances are ~90% that any configuration file that sets your IP will be in `/etc`. Specifically, it will probably be `/etc/network/interfaces`.